# How to set up authorization using js-SSR and SPA?

Tags: session, cookies, authorization, single-page-application, server-side-rendering

I want to develop my own single page web application (SPA) to get to grips with the modern and highly fluid world of web development. At the same time, I would like to use the page rendering technology (SSR) with built in data into html. However, there is an authorization problem.

Suppose that the user has already logged into the account before, as I imagine re-opening the site:

1. First request: the client makes a request to the frontend server along with identification and authorization data (for example, user id and token; the only option is to save them in cookies), the frontend server makes a request to the api server, transferring these service data, then the api server gives the information about the user and the content of the current page (in the same json), the frontend server renders this into a finished page and delivers it to the client.
2. Subsequent requests: the client directly addresses the api server, transferring the same (or updated after the first request) authorization data, receives json and processes it independently.

Actually, I want to move on to the question. Do I understand this interaction correctly? Can you do it differently / better? Are there tools that allow, for example, to use the components of the frontend framework as components of the MVC backend framework, so that one server does the rendering without unnecessary requests? Or a unified tool that includes the same coding for the frontend and backend to solve these problems? I will say right away that I would not like to write a backend in JS.

I can roughly imagine how you can get by with one request when using AngularJS (with a module for single page applications) and any backend MVC framework; although there will not be a full-fledged render, but search robots will not have to wait for my first fetch, since the data will be delivered initially, for example, through the data attribute. But in this case, I plan to choose Svelte (Sapper) and Ruby on Rails as the stack, although I think this is not important.

Thank you for your attention to the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Are there tools that allow, for example, to use the components of the frontend framework as components of the MVC backend framework, so that one server does the rendering without unnecessary requests?
```

If that's what you want you can install a frontend framework in Rails using webpacker. After that you will have a folder in your rails project that will contain your Svelte components. Then you import Svelte components in erb templates and pass data as props.

I have tried that approach but personally I prefer a separate frontend and backend talking through API calls. Then in your frontend you need something like Sapper if  you need SSR. With webpacker you don't(assuming you mostly use Rails for routing).

If you are worried about authorization it's not really hard to implement. And after login you can store user info on local storage for instance for subsequent requests. But of course if you install with webpacker it's all done within Rails hence it's easier.

From my experience, using webpacker it's easy and quick in the beginning but you are more likely to get headaches in the future. With separate backend and frontend takes a bit more work, especially in the beginning, but it's smoother in the long run.

[This](https://blog.usejournal.com/rails-api-jwt-auth-vuejs-spa-eb4cf740a3ae) helped me set the authentication between rails api and vue frontend.

So, if you wish to separate them, just install Rails as API only and I suggest you to use Jbuilder to build your jsons and serve them to the frontend as you need them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, I also want to move from a monolithic application to a split into a frontend and a backend, which is commonplace for future balancing. If you say that this is the correct implementation, that there will be no particular problems in the future, and that I have correctly described this scheme with the "forwarding" of the cookies (same-site) through the front-end server, then this is great news. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated the answer. If it answer your question, you can accept it :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with js-SSR to accept answers to questions like this, and even now I've only heard “it's not really hard”, so let's wait for someone more qualified on this topic to accept your answer.

Comment: FYI The person that asks the question must accept the answer, not someone else..